# How do I extend MyBatis to support a new database?

Tags: mybatis, mybatis-generator

I need to port MyBATIS to a new type of database (a custom one)...I guess I need to write a SqlSessionFactory that is relevant to my database?

Can you please refer me to the documentation on how I can extend it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think you have to do anuthing fancy. Having a server pool or just using your own driver would be enough. Here is the document I've used for my needs http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/